# hazards in a three-way superscalar pipeline

Tags: pipeline, cpu-registers, cpu-architecture

I am working my way though exercises relating to superscalar architecture.  I need some help conceptualizing the answer to this question:

> “If you ever get confused about what a register renamer has to do, go back to the assembly code you're executing, and ask yourself what has to happen for the right result to be obtained. For example, consider a three-way superscalar machine renaming these three instructions concurrently:
>
> ```
> ADDI R1, R1, R1
> ADDI R1, R1, R1
> ADDI R1, R1, R1
> ```
>
> If the value of R1 starts out as 5, what should its value be when this sequence has executed?”

I can look at that and see that, ok, the final value of R1 should be 40.  How would a three-way superscalar machine reach this answer though?  If I understand them correctly, in this three-way superscalar pipeline, these three instructions would be fetched in parallel. Meaning, you would have a hazard right from start, right? How should I conceptualize the answer to this problem?

EDIT 1:  When decoding these instructions, the three-way superscalar machine would, by necessity, have to perform register renaming to get the following instruction set, correct:

> ```
>   ADDI R1, R2, R3
>   ADDI R4, R5, R6
>   ADDI R1, R2, R3
> ```

Comment: Could the instruction set be renamed as follows:

ADDI R2, R1, R1

ADDI R3, R2, R2

ADDI R4, R3, R3
?

Please correct me if I am wrong.

Answer (score 3):

Simply put - you won't be able to perform these instructions together. However, the goal of this example doesn't seem to do with hazards (namely - detecting that these instruction are interdependent and must be performed serially with sufficient stalls), it's about **renaming** - it serves to show that a single logical register (R1) will have multiple physical "versions" in-flight simultaneously in the pipeline. The original one would have the value 5 (lets call it "p1"), but you'll also need to allocate one for the result of the first ADD ("p2"), to be used as source for the second, and again for the results of the second and third ADD instructions ("p3" and "p4").

Since this processor decodes and attempts to issue these 3 instructions simultaneously, you can see that you can't just have R1 as the source for all - that would prevent each of them from using the correct mid-calculation value, so you need to rename them. The important part is that p1..p4 as we've dubbed them, can be allocated simultaneously, and the dependencies would be known at the time of issue - long before each of them is populated with the result. This essentially decouples the front-end from the execution back-end, which is important for the performance flexibility in modern CPUs as you may have bottlenecks anywhere.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I made an edit (edit 1). Would the third instruction be ok like that, or would there need to be register renaming there as well?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the original version, except that it won't use the 3-wide pipe. And Renaming is something that's done all the time, the entire machine would "talk" in physical register IDs past some pipestage. By the way - your new code isn't doing the same thing as the original

Comment: Point taken. Generally, how would I conceptualize how the registers are renamed?

Comment: Just assume that any new result gets its own register, and all dependencies are updated accordingly. This breaks all false dependencies.